# Python urllib2.Request title response unreadable for instagram

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

i am having this code below:

```
def check_proxy(input_queue):
    while 1:
        prx = input_queue.get()
        try:
            proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': prx})
            opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
            opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
            urllib2.install_opener(opener)
            req = urllib2.Request("http://www.google.com")
            sock = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=7)
            rs = sock.read(1000)
            if '<title>Google</title>' in rs:
                print '[OK]', prx
                input_queue.task_done()
```

I've changed checking Google.com to instagram.com

and I've changed the title to Instagram

But it doesn't work for some reason.

I've checked "print rs" for instagram. and got this title:

```
        <title>
Instagram
</title>
```

Just wonder how to make it work to check for https://www.instagram.com instead of google.com

Thank you

Comment: It redirects to HTTPS. You sure you're handling that properly?

Comment: @Alfabravo I've tried my best with failed attempt. can you help me out. thank you.

Comment: Using python2 or python3?

Comment: @Alfabravo Python 2.7.5

Comment: What's in the LIST of files?

Comment: @Alfabravo proxies (IP:PORT) format. try these: https://gist.github.com/mzaboss/a0281bc600a60f8a3c2bff30c24db1ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string to match the title in Instagram's HTML should be `'<title>\nInstagram\n<title>`. Google's does not have newlines in their HTML, but Instagram does.